# python, while loop, function called inside function

Tags: python, function, while-loop, cs50

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm using cs50IDE to write some code that does carats and weights calculations. The `bring_up(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct, target_per1000)` function doesn't seem to work properly.
When I run the following code and I opt for `"yes"` at `"Would you like to bring the carats up to {target_ct}ct/{target_per1000}? "` instead of printing the last output, the cursor remains active in the console and if I quit the program this message comes up:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "carats.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "carats.py", line 29, in main
    to_add = bring_up(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct, target_per1000)
  File "carats.py", line 61, in bring_up
    result = calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, new_18ct, _22ct)
  File "carats.py", line 39, in calc_ct
    result = int((a+b+c+d)/tot_weight)
KeyboardInterrupt`
```

I have tried to include `print(new_18ct)` and `print(result)` in the while loop in the `bring_up(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct, target_per1000)` function and it seems stuck in the loop.
I've tried to substitute the while loop whit a `if...else` structure and the result is that it prints the last sentence of the main function as follows:

```
 You need to add **None**gr of {target_ct}ct
```

I hope you can help me, thank you!!!

````
`
    # work out resulting carat from mixed carats

    from cs50 import get_float, get_string



def main():
    # prompt user for weight of different carats:
    print("Insert weight in grams of customers gold in the following carats:")
    _9ct = get_float("9ct: ")
    _14ct = get_float("14ct: ")
    _18ct = get_float("18ct: ")
    _22ct = get_float("22ct: ")
    #calculate resulting carats and weight after loss in casting
    result = calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct)
    minusloss = format(((_9ct + _14ct + _18ct + _22ct) * 0.95), '.2f')

    print()
    print(f"Estimated resulting carats: {result}ct")
    print()

    # check if user wants to achieve specific carat weight
    target_ct, target_per1000 = target(result)
    check = get_string(f"Would you like to bring the carats up to {target_ct}ct/{target_per1000}? ")
    if check.lower() in ["n", "no"]:
        print(f"Remember to consider a 5% loss: total weight({(_9ct + _14ct + _18ct + _22ct)}gr) -5% = {minusloss}gr")
        print("See you next time!")
    elif check.lower() in ["y", "yes"]:
        # calculate how much metal of each carat they need to add to
        to_add = bring_up(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct, target_per1000)
        print(f"You need to add {to_add}gr of {target_ct}ct")


def calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct):
    a = _9ct * 375
    b = _14ct * 585
    c = _18ct * 750
    d = _22ct * 916
    tot_weight = _9ct + _14ct + _18ct + _22ct
    result = int((a+b+c+d)/tot_weight)
    return result

def target(result):
    target_ct = 0
    target_per1000 = 0
    if result > 375 and result < 585:
        target_ct = 14
        target_per1000 = 585
    if result > 585 and result < 750:
        target_ct = 18
        target_per1000 = 750
    if result > 750 and result < 916:
        target_ct = 22
        target_per1000 = 916
    return target_ct, target_per1000

def bring_up(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct, target_per1000):
    to_add = 0
    result = calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct)
    while result < target_per1000:
        new_18ct = _18ct + 0.5
        result = calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, new_18ct, _22ct)
        to_add += 0.5
    return to_add

main()
```


----------
````

Comment: You're entering into an infinite loop. That error is the console telling you that you manually interrupted the program.

Comment: I recommend putting some print statements in the while loop inside of bring_up that output the value of result, ie. print("result: ", result) print("new_18ct: ", new_18ct) print("to_add: ", to_add) -- Hopefully you'll see some values you weren't expecting and realize what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like, inside your loop, you are simply attributing a new value to your variable result everytime instead of adding up to it.
try to add up to the previous value by simple changing the attribution sign ('=') to increment ('+=')

```
def bring_up(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct, target_per1000):
    to_add = 0
    result = calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, _18ct, _22ct)
    while result < target_per1000:
        new_18ct = _18ct + 0.5
        result += calc_ct(_9ct, _14ct, new_18ct, _22ct)
        to_add += 0.5
    return to_add
```

welcome to programming :)